# Grunt: have package.json and Gruntfile.js on different folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs

Im having problems trying to implement grunt on diferent folders, in my root i have:

```
<root>/package.json
<root>/node_modules
```

And inside another folder, my gruntfile with diferent subfolders and files wich i work:

```
<root>/apps/static/Gruntfile.js
```

If i go to root and execute

```
grunt --gruntfile /apps/static/Gruntfile.js MyTaskName
```

I get:

> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-concat" not found. Is it installed?
>
> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-cssmin" not found. Is it installed?
>
> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-clean" not found. Is it installed?
>
> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-watch" not found. Is it installed?
>
> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-uglify" not found. Is it installed?

And i run several times npm install.

On my gruntfile.js y have

`grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');`

`grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');`

`grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');`

`grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');`

`grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');`

I triple check and folders are ok (in fact, originally gruntfile and package where in the same folder and everything was working perfect, run several task and everything is ok). I really need to have a common package.json and node_modules on root and the Gruntfile.js on a specific project folder

Any idea whats going on? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grunt makes certain assumptions regarding the location of `gruntfile.js`.

When you specify the location of `gruntfile.js` using the `--gruntfile` option, Grunt [sets the current directory](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/v1.0.1/lib/grunt/task.js#L431-L437) to the directory containing the specified file:

```
// Change working directory so that all paths are relative to the
// Gruntfile's location (or the --base option, if specified).
process.chdir(grunt.option('base') || path.dirname(gruntfile));
```

And when Grunt loads NPM tasks, it does so [relative to the current directory](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/v1.0.1/lib/grunt/task.js#L373-L405):

```
var root = path.resolve('node_modules');
var pkgfile = path.join(root, name, 'package.json');
```

There is a [`--base` option](http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli#base-b) with which the current directory can be specifed, but whether or not that will solve your problem (without introducing other problems) I do not know. The simplest solution is likely to locate `gruntfile.js` where it wants and expects to be located.

Comment: I read about --base, but i still have problems, im in the root folder and i get:

A valid Gruntfile could not be found. Please see the getting started guide for
more information on how to configure grunt: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile. And the gruntfile is there. My problem is that this is a big project, and having everything on the same file it can be complicated. Im working 8 websites with this, and each one must have his specific grunt in order to make it easy

Comment: I think that in trying to locate `gruntfile.js` someplace it doesn't really want to be located, you're entering a world of pain. This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/338149). If your problem is complexity, Grunt has some other mechanisms that might offer less painful solutions (e.g. [`grunt.config.merge`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#grunt.config.merge)). I would suggest asking another question that asks how your complexity problem can be solved. I think the why-doesn't-this-work question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it may be the need of project to have `Gruntfile.js` in a different folder than `package.json`.

I had a very similar use-case where there were multiple submodules each with its own build process, one of them was Grunt. But at the same time I wanted to have a common `package.json` just to avoid multiple `node_modules` folders being created, so that common dependencies (including transitive) use to install once. It helped in reducing install time as well as disk usage.

I was expecting a solution in Grunt itself. But as @cartant mentioned, Grunt has made certain assumptions.

So, here is what I did:

In `Gruntfile.js`,

Define a function:

```
function loadExternalNpmTasks(grunt, name) {
  const tasksdir = path.join(root, 'node_modules', name, 'tasks');
  if (grunt.file.exists(tasksdir)) {
    grunt.loadTasks(tasksdir);
  } else {
    grunt.log.error('Npm module "' + name + '" not found. Is it installed?');
  }
}
```

And instead of

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
```

do:

```
loadExternalNpmTasks(grunt, 'grunt-contrib-concat');
```

Reference: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/task.js#L396